# Select table that has records existing in another table using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to get the records in citizen table that have a record in job table using LINQ. Can someone please translate this in LINQ? Thanks!

```
SELECT * FROM JOB_MSTR j where j.citizen_id IN (SELECT c.citizen_id from CITIZEN_MSTR c);
```

Comment: I'm trying `Any` but can't get the statement finished: `var citizens = from j in _odb.JOB_MSTR.Any(j => j.EMP_ID == (_odb.CITIZEN_MSTR .....))`. It's unfinished, I am so ashamed right now haha

Comment: Read about `Contains` keyword for LINQ

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/

Answer (score 3):

This sould do it

```
ctx.JOB_MSTR.Where(x => ctx.CITIZEN_MSTR.Any(y => y.citizen_id == x.citizen_id))
```

Comment: i used `ctx` as varialbe name for the context of your entity framework `using (EntityFoo ctx = new EntityFoo()){}`

Comment: I need the format like @LateshtClick 's (`from j in ctx.JOB_MSTR`), as I will put this in a variable and return it to View

Comment: I think it's still incomplete, because I still have to put it in a `Model` at the end of the LINQ like: `select new CitizenModel { id = c.CITIZEN_ID, fullName = c.FNAME + " " _ c.LNAME,.... };` That's why I'm getting confused with the answer, especially in x and y. I'm not sure if x pertains to `JOB_MSTR` and y pertains to `CITIZEN_MSTR`. I also can't see the alias delaration like this: `from j in ctx.JOB_MSTR` or `c in ctx.CITIZEN_MSTR`

Comment: Thanks @fubo! Btw, I declared it like `var result`, bec. this is what I did with all my `LINQ`s. It just felt pretty weird coding it like this because i was used to code `LINQ` like: `from j in ctx.JOB_MSTR..`. Anyway, so `c` pertains to `JOB_MSTR`, but how do I access `CITIZEN_MSTR`s columns? I can't do it using the x and y variables. The FNAME and LNAME are one of `CITIZEN_MSTR` 's columns

Comment: I think that's another question, your initial question was about `SELECT *` not about creating a new `CitizenModel` and you also didn't ask for query syntax which is way old fashioned imo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397947.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = ( from j in ctx.JOB_MSTR 
                       join c in ctx.CITIZEN_MSTR
                      on j.citizen_id equals c.citizen_id 
                      select j).ToList();
```

Comment: that's more like `SELECT j.* FROM JOB_MSTR j join CITIZEN_MSTR c on j.citizen_id = c.citizen_id;` which doesn't return JOB_MSTR rows unique

Comment: @fubo but i need the `LINQ` in this format, so I can put it in a variable. Can you edit your answer? Thank you!